# Running a block of code in a backing bean whenever a Facelet page loads

Tags: jsf, session, jsf-2, facelets

I am using JSF to build a website. I want to run a block of code when the Facelet page loads everytime, I need use a session scope backing bean. I tried using the constructor of the backing bean to run the block of codes but it runs only for the first time, I was using the following codes

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.statusList}"
                        varStatus="loop">
```

Since `statusBean` is session scoped, it runs the constructor for the first time when the page is loaded.

Is there any other alternative to run the block of code whenever the page loads, not only for first time?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this. First of all, you must define what you mean with "when the Facelets page loads". I assume you mean before the page is rendered.

**PreRenderViewEvent**

With JSF 2.x the simplest way to do this is a system event listener for `PreRenderViewEvent`. For this you first need a `f:event` tag in your page like this:

```
<f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent"
    listener="#{bean.preRenderView}"/>
```

Listeners for `PreRenderViewEvent` must be registered on the view root (`f:view`). So `f:event` must be a direct child of `f:view` or somewhere top level if you do not use `f:view`. With templating `f:event` must be put inside a `ui:define` that guarantees the same.

The listener method referenced in the `listener` attribute is called before the view is rendered. The method might look like this:

```
public void preRenderView(ComponentSystemEvent ev) {
    //Do something
}
```

**@PreRenderView**

If you use CDI with MyFaces CODI, you can simply annotate a managed bean method with `@PreRenderView` and it will be called before the page is rendered.

**View actions**

With JSF 2.2 (not yet final) you can use view actions to call methods at different phases of the lifecycle. See my [JSFlive post on JSF 2.2 view actions](http://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/jsf22-view-actions/) for details.

You can find examples for `PreRenderViewEvent` and view actions in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/jsflive/jsf-get-examples)

Comment: Note that `<c:forEach>` runs during view build time, not during view render time. So, the pre render view event is too late. OP's best bet would be splitting request/view scoped data into a request/view scoped bean and injecting the session scoped bean in there.

Comment: @BalusC It would be really helpful if you could elaborate on how to inject session scoped bean in request/view scoped bean.

Comment: Or even simpler: throw away `c:forEach` and use `ui:repeat` instead - it is a component and evaluated at rendering.

Comment: @Amlan Btw. maybe you should give us some details on what you want to achieve. There might be another, simpler way of doing it.

Comment: @Michi I tried using `ui:repeat` but I was having some issues with it. So I tried switching to `c:forEach`. The current problem that I am having is that wherever i put the `f:event`, the backing bean function is not running.

Comment: Listeners for `PreRenderViewEvent` must be registered on the view root (`f:view`). So `f:event` must be a direct child of `f:view` or somewhere top level in your page if you do not use `f:view`. Do you use templating? Because then special care has to be taken.

Comment: @Michi I have put `f:event` under `f:view` on the top of the page after the  `html` tag but still the function in the backing bean is not called. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. The bean is session scoped.

Comment: Do you have this signature (name is not relevant):

`public void preRenderView(ComponentSystemEvent ev)`

Comment: yes I have `public void init(ComponentSystemEvent event)` signature in the backing bean. I have used `System.out.println` line to print to the console whenever it enters the function but it turns out it not entering the function.

Comment: You can have a look at my example jsf-get01 https://github.com/jsflive/jsf-get-examples (view productDetails.xhtml).

Comment: p.s. JSF 2.2 is now final ;)